# Initialize a struct with previous declared array

Tags: c, arrays, struct, initialization, initializer-list

I have the following situation:

```
typedef struct A {
    unsigned int a[4];
} A_;

int main() {
    unsigned int b[4] = {1,2,3,4};
    A_ a = {b};
}
```

This is making me get the following warning:

> warning: initialization of 'unsigned int' from 'unsigned int *' makes
>   integer from pointer without a cast

But making this `A_ a = {{1,2,3,4}};` is ok. Why?

Comment: `A_ a = {.a = b};` works for me.

Comment: Actually no. It compiles, but does not work.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: I doubt it. Can you show an example with Godbolt?

Comment: @EricPostpischil You are right, added another comment just before yours. Not sure what it does...https://ideone.com/k2xOIj

Comment: @EugeneSh.: It does exactly what the message shown in the question says it does: Make an integer from a pointer without a cast. The grammar makes `b` an *assignment-expression*, so it is converted to a pointer to its first element, and that is used to initialize the first `int` in `a.a`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Got it, thanks

Comment: Try `int main() {
    unsigned int b[4] = {1,2,3,4};
    A_ a = {{b[0], b[1], b[2], b[3]}};
    printf("%d\n", a.a[0]);
}` to _Initialize a struct with previous declared array_.

Comment: @EugeneSh. the code is erroneous; but, for unclear reasons, gcc categorizes the mistake as a warning, and ideone.com suppresses gcc warnings

Comment: I think gcc categorizes as a warning because we can convert int to almost anything. I believe that if I change to double, I would get an error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard C does not provide any mechanism to initialize a structure member with an array, except for initializing arrays with string literals.

Instead, you can initialize the structure with a structure. Assuming the values you want to use are known when the code is written, the latter structure can also be made `static const`:

```
int main(void)
{
    static const A_ InitialStructure = {{ 1, 2, 3, 4 }};
    A_ a = InitialStructure;
}
```